# What is the point of subtracting in this index of an array?

Tags: c, arrays

```
main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];

    nwhite = nother = 0;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
        ndigit[i]=0;

    while((c=getchar()) != EOF)
        if(c>='0' && c<='9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        else if(c==' ' || c=='\n' || c == '\t')
            ++nwhite;
        else
            ++nother;

    printf("digits =");
    for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n", nwhite, nother);


}
```

What is the point of having the index like this? `++ndigit[c-'0'];` As opposed to this: `++ndigit[c];` or am I totally looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: Well, no one knows in what way you're looking at it, but it's certainly the wrong way if it doesn't account for the difference between 0 ... 9 and '0' ... '9'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, when you use getchar(), it returns an int but with the values of a char. In chars the numbers '0' to '9' aren't actually stored numerically as 0 to 9 but as 48 to 57. That is to say '0' is not the same as 0 but actually the same as 48. Therefore, in this case, let's say c is '0'. If you just did nDigits[c] it would be the same as nDigits[48] when what you want is nDigits[0] so you need to do nDigits[c - '0'] which translates to nDigits[48 - 48] which is nDigits[0]... which is what you want!

Comment: So 0 in c programming is not the same as '0', gotcha!

Comment: @Doug 0 isn't the same as '0' in any programming, although some languages, such as perl, will convert one to the other in some contexts.

Answer (score 4):

The ASCII character for `0` is not the actual zero byte `\0`.  Thus, if you did `a['0']`, you would actually be doing `a[48]` (on an ASCII system), and so subtracting `'0'` converts the digit to an integer value.

Answer (score 2):

getChar() is returning a character.  So c-'0', if c == '0'. results in the integer 0.

Answer (score 1):

ndigit[c] will get you an array index somewhere around the ascii value of '0'->'9', or 48-57.  By subtracting '0', you bring it down to the 0 to 9 range.